# Add zero's to string

Tags: c, parsing, sniffer

I have a C program which captures data, and among them it captures MAC Addresses. However, while the MAC might be for example `00:0F:3A:D3`, the program captures it like `0:F:3A:D3`. Is there a way to check the string and see if between two " `:` " there's one character, and if so to add a zero in front ?

I'm not a good programmer, so any help is appreciated - Thanks :)

Comment: Emm... You look at the string and inspect several adjacent characters and decide whether it's that situation. What's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int main() {
    char *s = "0:F:3A:D3";
    char o[15];
    int a, b, c, d;
    sscanf(s, "%X:%X:%X:%X", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    sprintf(o, "%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X", a, b, c, d);
    printf(o);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the printf modifier `%02X` to output a hexadecimal number with a leading zero.

If you receive this string in such a format from another application, I would suggest fixing that other application rather than adapting your code.